# Loading Images for gallery from Custom folder

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-image, android-gallery

I am trying to load images and show them as a gallery in the form of list. 
The problem is that I am able to do it from default android gallery, but I don't know how to do t for custom folder. for e.g /Pictures folder. I have been trying, here is the code that I use for default gallery, I want it for some other folder, e.g /Pictures/Col.

```
    public static List<PhotoItem> getAlbumThumbnails(Context context){
    final String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID};
    Cursor thumbnailsCursor = context.getContentResolver().query( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            projection, // Which columns to return
            null, // Return all rows
            null,
            null);
// Extract the proper column thumbnails
        int thumbnailColumnIndex = thumbnailsCursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.DATA);
        ArrayList<PhotoItem> result = new ArrayList<PhotoItem>(thumbnailsCursor.getCount());
        if (thumbnailsCursor.moveToFirst()) {
            do {
// Generate a tiny thumbnail version.
                int thumbnailImageID = thumbnailsCursor.getInt(thumbnailColumnIndex);
                String thumbnailPath = thumbnailsCursor.getString(thumbnailImageID);
                Uri thumbnailUri = Uri.parse(thumbnailPath);
                Uri fullImageUri = uriToFullImage(thumbnailsCursor,context);
// Create the list item.
                PhotoItem newItem = new PhotoItem(thumbnailUri,fullImageUri);
                result.add(newItem);
            } while (thumbnailsCursor.moveToNext());
        }
        thumbnailsCursor.close();
        return result;
    }
```

What all should I change here, I tried to change projection, query parameters but failed, new in this field, please help :)

Answer (score 0):

You can custom [recent-images](https://github.com/amirarcane/recent-images) library for your purpose. It's very simple and easy to use library.